# What is the recommended action on receving ChangeFeedObserverCloseReason.ObserverError?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My ChangeFeedProcessor's IChangeFeedObserver.CloseAsync callback was invoked with ChangeFeedObserverCloseReason as "ObserverError". So, far I have seen this error only once and I am not sure how to repro it. What causes this error? Is there a way to diagnose this more? Is there any recommended action that one should take after receiving this error?

Comment: Provide some code that you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I understand you are using [Change Feed Processor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet).

That Close reason is provided when the code in your `ProcessChangesAsync` implementation throws an unhandled exception.

Basically, if that happens, it means your code had an error processing the changes so:

1. The Observer is closed, releasing the Lease
2. The lease becomes available to be picked by any Host instance
3. The lease gets picked up by a Host, an Observer started, the same batch of changes gets sent to be processed
4. If the nature of your error was transient, then this time it will work (hopefully). If its not transient, then you will again face an ObserverError.

As a rule of thumb, always try to manage your exceptions if possible, if not, it will be treated as a temporary scenario and will get eventually retried as I described.

Also please next time give more context, describe which libraries and versions you are using and provide some related code. It will help a lot understanding and diagnosing.